# How do I create and retain bookmarks in qpdfview or qpdf? I was using Ctrl+b and saving my bookmarks but it's not permanent after restarting qpdf

Tags: linux, pdf, bookmarks, acrobat-reader, qpdfview

I think the main question is self-sufficient. To add things that I tried: I am on a linux machine so I was trying opensource options, and qpdf was the software I was already using. Tried to seek answer from google but couldn't find my answer from the links google indexed. Tried getting answers from [chatgpt](https://chat.openai.com/c/023dda26-9b64-4a4c-8a14-f4814f5bd80b) but it told me to use acrobat instead because qpdf is not as good as acrobat. Being on a linux machine I just installed acrobat using wine, but I still have to use acrobat. I thought of asking the question here while trying the acrobat way, because I would prefer something opensource.

Comment: [The change log Version 8.4.1: April 27, 2019 mentions](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/release-notes.html#release-notes) mentions *Revert change that included preservation of outlines (bookmarks) in --split-pages.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.